# Axios Post method authorization does not work - React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am developing a website [using React for front-end // Spring for backend] and in this website there is an admin panel. There is a button which lets other admins to add users to the database but I have a problem with axios' post method. 


I checked so many different sources but couldnt find exactly what I am looking for. So here I am.


I get this error,  [401 error code, unauthorized client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4wnF.png), when using this syntax below

```
async addUsers(newData){

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': window.$auth
          }

        await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8080/admin/addUser",  
            JSON.stringify(newData),  
            {headers: headers}
            );
    }
```

Before, I tried using a different syntax which I think is wrong, and with this syntax I get 415 error code: [415 error code, unsupported media type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfDQT.png)

```
async addUsers(newData){

        await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8080/admin/addUser",  
            JSON.stringify(newData),  
            {auth:window.$auth},
            {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}}
            );
    }
```

P.S: I tried to add User manually to database using Insomnia REST client and it successfully adds it and returns 200 Code.

 Could someone help me with this problem, please?

Comment: In the config of `Axios.post(url, data, config)` call the `headers` is to pass the `Authorization` field. Are you sure that `window.$auth` contains valid entry e.g. `"Bearer eyJ...30w"`

Comment: Axios doesn't need `body` to be stringified, is one of it's gratefulls things :)

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela when, I console out `window.$auth` it logs:  `{username: "admin", password: "admin"} username: "admin" password: "admin"`  , so it should be correct

Comment: so this is not AFAIK the authorisation data you would expect that goes to authorization header `Authorization: <type> <credentials>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela So, I looked at the site you sent and I modified the code: `const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(window.$auth.username + ':' + window.$auth.password) 
          }` . This way when I console out the `btoa(window.$auth.username + ':' + window.$auth.password) ` ->  `YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`, its something like this, but still does not work :(

Comment: I'm not sure you are having right authorisation to access your resource, whichever you connect to should have some sort of indication what authorisation is required and you should follow.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I fixed it. The problem was with Axios' Post syntax. I changed it to a different one and it worked. Thanks for the help . :)

Comment: glad it worked, however I'm using this syntax for posting authorised and it works for my, however I do have the Bearer option not like you Basic... But looking again at your snippet `'Basic' + btoa...` shouldnt it contain a space after Basic? :) Anyways glad you've resolved it.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I don't wanna go back and find out what I spent hours to fix it was a simple 'space' mistake, so im gonna leave it as this :)) Side note: it seems on the website that I found the solution this only happens with Basic auth. Maybe thats why it works you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this "authorization always returning 401 error code" was a known issue. Changing the complete syntax fixed it. Here is the site that I found the solution on https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/926 
 
Here is the part of my code which that I fixed and now works:

```
async addUsers(newData){

        await Axios({
            method:'post',
            url:'http://localhost:8080/admin/addUser',
            data:JSON.stringify(newData),
            auth:window.$auth,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending authorization token with each request better add it as a default header. First check if token exist if it is exist add it

```
if(authorization_token){
 axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authorization_token;
}
```

Comment: at the time when your receive token, In authentication api response, I t must be returning token to you. Save it in localstorage and use it from there.